# Name image avatar as "user.uid.jpg", is it safe?

Tags: firebase, storage, firebase-storage

I would like your thought, is it safe to name my user's avatar image with their "uid.jpg" ? This way it's easier to request, but it means anyone who could eventually download the image will have my user's uid... Firebase is working with a ionic/cordova smartphone app.

The other way is to generate a name using a timestamp, like "timestamp+random number.jpg", and store it into my user's profil, maybe the safer way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use "_" or "-" signs instead of "."
Correct image or other file names are "user_uid.jpg" and "user-uid.jpg".
And please avoid to show user info like its id "uid", use some encryption mothod to change file name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my concerning is about the safety of this method, is it safe enough to let my user'uid in the image name ? I mean, could it be a security back door or something ?

Comment: I am glade that it worked for you, please up-vote my answer.